# ISNULL syntax in SQL pivot

Tags: sql, pivot, isnull

I have the following bit of code

```
SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(PERIOD)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PERIOD FROM @p_l_summary) AS b
ORDER BY b.PERIOD
```

which works perfectly but generates some NULL values.

I know that I need to wrap an ISNULL around the @columns but can anyone give me the right syntax - whatever I try either generates an error or seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about adding additional condition?

```
WHERE PERIOD IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

`COALESCE` returns the first non-null value, so it's acting as `ISNULL` in your case.
So your query can return null only if PERIOD column is null. You can either filter such values out:

```
SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(PERIOD)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PERIOD FROM @p_l_summary WHERE PERIOD IS NOT NULL) AS b
ORDER BY b.PERIOD
```

or use `ISNULL` on PERIOD:

```
SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ', ','') + ISNULL(QUOTENAME(PERIOD), '')
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PERIOD FROM @p_l_summary) AS b
ORDER BY b.PERIOD
```